# Gatsby - Pass state property to GraphQL query variables/parameter?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I am new to gatsby and graphQL and am trying to build a website with this stack that will display a list of concerts/events.

My question is:

Is it possible to pass data from my app state down to my query variables. Where do I connect my state and my graphQL query ?

Here is my code:

```
class IndexPage extends Component {

state = {
  term: '',
  date: null,
}


onTermChange(term) {
  this.setState({ term });
}

render() {
  return (
  <Layout>
    <SearchForm
      onTermChange={this.onTermChange.bind(this)}
      value={this.state.term}
    />

    <Calendar
      onChange={date => this.setState({ date })}
      value={this.state.date}

    />

    <StaticQuery
      query={graphql`
      query ComingEvents {
        allEvent(sort: {fields: [dateAndTime], order: ASC}) {
          edges {
            node {
              id
              name
              dateAndTime
              venue
              ticketsLink
              city
              thumbnail {
                id
                url
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }`
      }
      render={ data => (
        <EventsList
        events={data.allEvent.edges}
         />
      )}
     />
</Layout>

);
```

}
}

Basically this is what I want to do:

1. When the value of the search field form `this.state.term` changes, I want to pass this as $name parameter and query new results.
2. When the value of the date picked out in the calendar `this.state.date` changes, I want to pass this as $dateAndTime parameter and query new results.

Comment: You can't pass variable in query based on component state because data are retrieved on compilation time. You can get all your data and apply `.filter()` after

Comment: ok - my poor understanding of graphQL shows here. Its probably not the best stack for what I intend to do. I wanted to use graphCMS to create the content but if I have to rebuilt and deploy again each time there is new content to display (every 12hours). I am a bit confused because I query the GitHub graphAPI with my portfolio website and it updates almost in real time (using CRA and Apollo)

Comment: @Yannick yes, automated rebuilt and deploy is a core concept in gatsby. For a fairly small site that should be very fast ~ 30 sec as it's quite fast.

Comment: @Zlatev very nice, I'll look into this. Thank you.

Comment: Rebuilt and deploys are triggered by webhooks. With GraphCMS, webhooks are not available on the free plan unfortunetaly. I might have to choose another CMS.

Answer (score 0):

If someone else came across it. You can't pass variable as @ghuntheur said but if you want to get some list in build time this is useful example:

```
export const useGraphFlags = () => {
    const { allFile } = useStaticQuery(
        graphql`
            query GraphAllFile {
                allFile(filter: {relativeDirectory: { eq: "svg/flags" }}) {
                    nodes {
                        relativePath
                        publicURL
                        relativeDirectory
                    }
                }
            }
        `
    );
    return allFile.nodes;
};
```

later in component:

```
const flags = useGraphFlags();

return flags.map(file => (
    <img 
      key={file.relativePath} 
      src={file.publicURL} 
      alt=""
    />
));
```