# Error: BabelPluginRemoveGraphQL: String interpolations

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I am getting below error when trying to pass variable dynamically in gatsBy Graphql.

**Error**

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/gatsby/dist/utils/babel-loader.js):
Error: BabelPluginRemoveGraphQL: String interpolations are not allowed in graphql fragments. Included fragments should be referenced as `...MyModule_foo`.
```

**Query**

```
let mytext = 'welcome'
let myQuery = graphql`query($text: String = "${mytext}") {
            allGhostPost : allGhostPost(filter:{title:{eq: $text}}) {
              edges {
                node {
                  id
                  slug
                }
              }
            }
          }`
```

Please help!!!

Answer (score 3):

Inserting arbitrary text into queries like this is a [well-known security issue](https://www.xkcd.com/327/) and the Babel plugin is almost certainly right to forbid it.  GraphQL defines [a JSON-over-HTTP payload format](https://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/#post-request) that allows passing the variables separately (encoded as JSON objects to minimize the possibility of injection attacks).

You don't show what's actually making the query, but it should have a place to add a map of GraphQL variables.  (For example, the graphql-js reference implementation includes a `variableValues` parameter to [its top-level `graphql` function](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/graphql/#graphql).)  Remove the `= "${mytext}"` part of the query, and instead use a variables object like `{text: mytext}`.

Comment: Thank you but what is the solution? I need to pass dynamically `mytext`.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52844535/gatsby-pass-state-property-to-graphql-query-variables-parameter#comment92607401_52844535) suggests that you can not pass a variable to the string as the query is resolved at compile time.